# Misplaced \no align error

Tags: tables, report, hhline

I Have a problem when i would to insert \hline at the end of table , i have as error : "Misplaced \noalign 
\hline->\noalign"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[array,table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{16cm}
\begin{tabular}{|C{7.4cm}|C{7.4cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}Administrateur fonctionnel du reporting & Administrateur des habilitations du reporting\\ \hline 
\justify L'administrateur fonctionnel du reporting est une personne de la  MOA en charge de la définition, la mise en forme et la mise à disposition des reportings de l'application. &
\justify L'administrateur des habilitations du reporting est une personne de la MOA en charge de la gestion des habilitations et droits d'accès au portail de restitution de l'application.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Administrateurs du reporting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of declaring centering and then issuing `\justify`?

Comment: that's for centering a header , and justify for justify the content of cells

Comment: You should the other way around, then.

Comment: can you help me to resolve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that also `\justify` needs `\arraybackslash`. But you can better do the other way around: define justification for the cells and override it for the headers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[array,table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|m{7.4cm}|m{7.4cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{|C{7.4cm}|}{Administrateur fonctionnel du reporting} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{7.4cm}|}{Administrateur des habilitations du reporting}\\
\hline 
L'administrateur fonctionnel du reporting est une personne de la  MOA en
  charge de la définition, la mise en forme et la mise à disposition des
  reportings de l'application. &
L'administrateur des habilitations du reporting est une personne de la MOA
  en charge de la gestion des habilitations et droits d'accès au portail de
  restitution de l'application.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Administrateurs du reporting}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432023/5001), I recommend defining the table so that the main cell contents are automatically (fully) justified -- and adding commands to center-set the cell headers. Moreover, I'd assign the tedious business of calculating column widths to LaTeX (and the `tabularx` package). And, since you're using color (or grayness) to define the header block, I'd also dispense with all vertical lines and use fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} % width of A4 paper: 21cm
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % or: 'textwidth=16cm'

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\usepackage{tabularx}
%\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % uncomment if needed
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centering, allow line-breaking
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\rowcolor{Gray}
\mcc{Administrateur fonctionnel du reporting} & 
\mcc{Administrateur des habilitations du reporting}\\ 
L'administrateur fonctionnel du reporting est une personne 
de la  MOA en charge de la définition, la mise en forme et 
la mise à disposition des reportings de l'application. &
L'administrateur des habilitations du reporting est une 
personne de la MOA en charge de la gestion des 
habilitations et droits d'accès au portail de restitution 
de l'application.\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Administrateurs du reporting}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```